# O que vem no fluxo de TV digital?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, vídeo, áudio

Gostaria de saber quais os dados recebidos por uma televisão digital, sei que enviam uma descrição da programação e outros dados de controle, além da interatividade, mas, além desses e do vídeo/áudio, o que é recebido pelo fluxo?